# AS3 Concept similar to Event-Bubbling, in non-display-objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

Events in Flash/AS3 are very much linked to the display list. There is the capture, target, and bubbling phase, which is great when it comes to objects visible on the stage.

But is there a similar concept for non display objects, outside of the display list?

If we have objects A, B and C, where C was created in object B, and B was created in object A, and none of them are display objects: How can A listen for things happening in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem using at least two strategies:

1) Redispatching of events. Say `C` dispatches some event. In `B` we subscribe this event and redispatch it:

```
var c:C = new C();
c.addEventListener("myEvent", myEventHandler);

private function myEventHandler (event:Event):void
{
    dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Remember you should [implement `clone()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#clone%28%29) properly for your custom event class in this case.

You also can translate event from `C` to some other event in `B` and dispatch it.

2) Pass `C` to `A`. You can do it using [interface `flash.events.IEventDispatcher`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html).

Something like the following:

In `B`:

```
private var _c:IEventDispatcher;

public function get innerInstance():IEventDispatcher
{
    return _c;
}

public function B()
{
    _c = new C();
}
```

In `A`:

```
var b:B = new B();
b.innerInstance.addEventListener("myEvent", myEventHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think i understand how both of the strategies work, at least 1) is fully clear to me. 

I see it as a disadvantage to 'normal' display-list based event handling that the intermediate objects (B, in this case) has to be involved. But maybe there are no better alternatives.

But compared to "C calling a function in B, which calls a function in A", your methods are better of course, since the objects doesn't have to know their parents.

Comment: You could save some code lines by writing c.addEventListener("myEvent", dispatchEvent);

Comment: @maxmc Wow! I didn't think about it. As for me it is a brilliant idea! Thank you for pointing that!